# Overloading Multiple Functions with Same Parameters

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, overloading, return-type

I'm given to understand, thanks to the VC++ compiler, that you cannot overload functions with only a differing return type.

```
class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass MyClass::operator+(MyClass other) {
        return MyClass(n + other.getn());
    }
    MyClass() = default;
    MyClass(int my_n) : n{ my_n } {}
    int getn() {
        return n;
    }
private:
    int n{ 0 };
};

int main(){
    MyClass m1(7), m2(5);
    MyClass m3 = m1 + m2;
    return 0;
}
```

However, what if I would like to return an integer, say 12, when I add them, I cannot simply add them together and overload the operator+ again because it doesn't allow overloading where the only difference is the return type. I'm very new to C++. The only solution I could come up with is:

```
int i = (m1+m2).getn();
```

But that seems wasteful to create an instance when you will never use it again.

Comment: What's your question? Why function overloading with only diffrent return type is not allowed?

Comment: A MyClass is no more expensive than an int - so why are you worried about creating an extra int you will never use again?

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want is to be able to write `int i = m1 + m2;`, which means you should create a conversion operator.

```
class MyClass
{
    operator int()
    {
        return n;
    }
};

int i = m1 + m2; //creates temporary, calls operator int, saves value in i
```

It will still create a temporary, but that's how `operator+` works. You could always write `int i = m1.getn() + m2.getn();`, too.

Answer (score 0):

Overloading doesn't consider about return type.

From the standard, $13.3/1 Overload resolution [over.match]

> The selection criteria for the best function are the number of arguments, how well the arguments
>   match the parameter-type-list of the candidate function, how well (for non-static member functions) the object matches the implicit object parameter, and certain other properties of the candidate function.

and

> 128) ... candidate call functions that cannot be differentiated one from the other by overload
>   resolution because they have identical declarations or differ only in their return type.

You might want to provide two `operator+` for `MyClass`, they only differ at the return type of `MyClass` and `int`, and use them as

```
MyClass m1(7), m2(5);
MyClass m3 = m1 + m2;
int x = m1 + m2;
```

but the return value could be omitted, then which one should be invoked? It's ill-formed.

```
m1 + m2;
// or m1.operator+(m2);
```

You could provide another named member function for it, such as

```
class MyClass { public:
    int add_return_int(MyClass other) {
        return n + other.getn();
    }
...
```

or as free function

```
int add_return_int(MyClass lhs, MyClass rhs) {
    return lhs.getn() + rhs.getn();
}
```